# Как анализировать громкость звука с аудиокарты с помощью BASS.Net?

Tags: c#, bass.dll, bass.net

я пытаюсь написать программу способную анализировать громкость всего звука звука в левом и правом канале. Однако все примеры работы с BASS.NET сводятся к воспроизведению звука из файла. Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Comment: [Слышали про NAudio](https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/5.php)?

Comment: смотрим пример [здесь](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797537/Making-an-Audio-Spectrum-analyzer-with-Bass-dll-Cs)

Comment: [ccылка](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797537/Making-an-Audio-Spectrum-analyzer-with-Bass-dll-Cs) Это решения я видел, однако оно имеет в себе слишком много подслоёв из-за чего я не могу добраться до самой сути